# Is it possible to do netstat for remote Linux system without password?

Tags: shell, psexec, netstat, remote-login

Help me with the shell script for the remote system to check the TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

In the remote, add your user to the wheel group:

```sh
sudo useradd -mG wheel -s /bin/bash $USER
```

Then, open `sudoers` file:

```sh
sudo vim /etc/sudoers
```

Add this line:

```sh
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: <command>
```

where you replace `<command>` with the actual command you desire. I'm not sure if a logout is needed for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i cant do this steps in the VM's because all are security enhanced and this VM's are  offering services to the customers. But i have the IP address of all the 3k Vm's.

Comment: To run a command that requires root privilege, you either 1) need to be root, 2) provide root password, or 3) tell the OS to skip asking for password for specific commands/users/groups from now on.

For all of these, you need root password and they can't be done without one.